# Angular2+ build with webpack and separate each file

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am not sure if it is possible in a nice way.

I have two goals:

1. Separate each TypeScript file in my source to one JavaScript file in my distribution. With other words, let the folder structure from source as the same as in my build distribution folder. The goal behind is a security check on my server. It is necessary to check if some specific JavaScript files in a folder are still the same (checksum). For that one big bundled file is not an option for me.
2. With the requirements above is it still possible to lazy load modules from my SPA? I need the power to optimize the performance and load modules when they are needed.